# "Multi-dimensional arrays are not supported" error when saving an object to IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSetting

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have tried searching Google and here and haven't come up with anything good. Any help would be appreciated.

Wherever I try try to add my own object to the user settings the app falls over. The Game class is fairly simple, a few string and int properties. If its relevant I can update the post with the full details.

Whenever I set the value of CurrentGame1 it falls over on the save method with the error "Multi-dimensional arrays are not supported.". Will I need to serialize the object? I would rather not have the complication if I can avoid it

```
    private Game CurrentGame1
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.SingleOrDefault(z => z.Key == "Game1").Key == null) {
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("Game1", new Game());
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
            }

            return IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Game1"] as Game;


        }
        set
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("Game1");
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("Game1", value);
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: the relevant code here is the Game class - that's where you have presumably defined a multidimensional array which can't be automatically serialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your multidimensional array ( foo[x,y] ) to an array of arrays ( foo[x][y] )  instead.

Answer (score 1):

Any object you pass to must support serialization (and deserialization) I would guess that the way you are defining `Game` you are not enabling this.

I would however recommend serializing (and deserializing) the object yourself though as IsolatdStorage uses the `DataContractSerializer` internally and this is very slow.
If you can serializer the object faster yourself and then pass a simple type to the IsolatedStorageSettings then you should be able to get better performance.